# Can't find TextView in another View

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I can't find the mistake. I want to set the text of a textview. But when I'm setting the text I get an error message (see below for this). What I'm doing wrong? 
A little further down I call a button. This call works perfectly. What am I doing wrong when I call up the text view and set the text of this?

```
private void popUp(int layout, int button) {
    epicDialog.setContentView(layout);
    epicDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

    TextView test = (TextView) epicDialog.findViewById(R.id.textView_popup);
    test.setText("Hello");

    ....
   Button button;
    button= epicDialog.findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // do something
        }

    });        
}
```

the error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: please post your layouts and popup is where? in Activity? and what is epidDialog? what type is it? Please put all necessary information

Comment: post 'layout' code

Comment: Seems to me your issue could be context. You are correct in using ```epicDialog.setContentView(layout);```
I have done something similar with progress dialog but I needed to show it before setting the contentview so.epicDialog.show(); It could be the id being incorrect as well. Also check textview is imported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot to show the dialog before finding the textview.

```
 private void popUp(int layout, int button) {
        epicDialog.setContentView(layout);
        epicDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        epicDialog.show();

        TextView test = (TextView) epicDialog.findViewById(R.id.textView_popup);
        test.setText("Hello");

        ....
       Button button;
        button= epicDialog.findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // do something
            }

        });        
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you add wrong id in java code.
check your xml.

```
android:id="@+id/textView"
```